# MacOS randomly disconnecting from WIFI

Tags: macos, wifi

I have a weird issue with MacOS (Catalina 10.15.4, MacBook Pro 15-inch, 2019) disconnecting from my WiFi (Ruckus R500). I have started "Wireless Diagnostics" to see what the problem is, but I couldn't find a clear problem.

The problem is specifically the case of the macbook and Ruckus R500. I have other (Windows) laptop that works well on this WiFI and doesn't drop. I also use this macbook at work where we have Ubiquity Unifi AP and it doesn't drop there.

As I'm no expert in this, I don't know what I should be providing - happy to have feedback from the community, but below are some of the information I got from diagnostics.

Here are some error strings I found in from wifi log:

```
Sat Jul 11 18:02:15.100 Info: <airportd[62494]> -[CWXPCSubsystem queryBSSIDForInterfaceWithName:connection:error:]: Failed to query current BSSID, returned error code -3903

Sun Jul 12 11:31:15.732 <airportd[62494]> ERROR: rapportd (343) is not entitled for com.apple.wifi.join_history, will not allow request
Sun Jul 12 11:31:15.732 <airportd[62494]> ERROR: sharingd (429) is not entitled for com.apple.wifi.join_history, will not allow request

Sun Jul 12 11:31:15.809 Info: <airportd[62494]> -[CWXPCInterfaceContext __setAWDLOperatingMode:interface:error:]: attempting to set AWDL mode to 0

Sun Jul 12 11:31:28.068 Info: <airportd[62494]> -[CWXPCSubsystem clearScanCacheWithInterfaceName:daemon:familyAndDriver:connection:error:]: Clearing family+driver scan cache for interface en0


Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.308 Assoc: <airportd[62494]> Will associate to [ssid=RN, bssid=90:3a:72:3b:6f:dc, channel=(channel=149, width=80), ibss=no, cc=US, rssi=-44, rsn=(mcast=aes_ccm, ucast={ aes_ccm }, auths={ psk ft_psk }, caps=0x0), wpa=(null), wep=no]
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.316 Roam: <airportd[62494]> FAILED to query roaming profile for 2.4GHz band on en0, returned error 102
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.316 Roam: <airportd[62494]> FAILED to update roaming profile for 2.4GHz band to SINGLE-BAND, SINGLE-AP, returned error 102
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.316 Roam: <airportd[62494]> FAILED to query roaming profile for 5GHz band on en0, returned error 102
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.316 Roam: <airportd[62494]> FAILED to update roaming profile for 5GHz band to SINGLE-BAND, SINGLE-AP, returned error 102
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.319 <airportd[62494]> _SC_callback: Changed keys = { 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/ProfileID' 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/WEP40' }
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.320 SC: <airportd[62494]> airportdProcessSystemConfigurationEvent: Processing 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/ProfileID'
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.320 SC: <airportd[62494]> airportdProcessSystemConfigurationEvent: Processing 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/WEP40'
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.320 <airportd[62494]> _SC_callback: Changed keys = { 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/BluetoothPagingInProgress ' 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/AirPlay' }
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.320 SC: <airportd[62494]> airportdProcessSystemConfigurationEvent: Processing 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/BluetoothPagingInProgress '
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.320 SC: <airportd[62494]> airportdProcessSystemConfigurationEvent: Processing 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/AirPlay'
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.321 <airportd[62494]> _SC_callback: Changed keys = { 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/AutoJoinTimestamp' 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/CHANNEL' 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/Busy' }
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.322 SC: <airportd[62494]> airportdProcessSystemConfigurationEvent: Processing 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/AutoJoinTimestamp'
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.322 SC: <airportd[62494]> airportdProcessSystemConfigurationEvent: Processing 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/CHANNEL'
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.322 SC: <airportd[62494]> airportdProcessSystemConfigurationEvent: Processing 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/Busy'
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.323 Assoc: <airportd[62494]> -[CWXPCSubsystem __associateToWiFiNetwork:tetherDevice:password:is8021X:passpointDomain:remember:possiblyHidden:updateUserKeychain:interface:processName:suspendAWDLToken:error:]_block_invoke: CWAWDMetricsOneStatsRecordAssocStats [WIFI_METRICS_ONESTATS_ASSOC_START_EVENT]
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.323 Info: <airportd[62494]> CWAWDMetricsOneStatsRecordAssocStats. Processing Event:1 
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.323 Info: <airportd[62494]> CWAWDMetricsOneStatsRecordAssocStats: OneStats is NOT Configured! No-op here- Returning!
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.323 <airportd[62494]> _SC_callback: Changed keys = { 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/Power Status' 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/WEPOPENSYSTEM' 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/UserMode8021X' 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/CachedScanRecord' 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/BluetoothAudioInUse' 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/BusyUI' }
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.323 SC: <airportd[62494]> airportdProcessSystemConfigurationEvent: Processing 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/Power Status'
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.323 SC: <airportd[62494]> airportdProcessSystemConfigurationEvent: Processing 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/WEPOPENSYSTEM'
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.323 SC: <airportd[62494]> airportdProcessSystemConfigurationEvent: Processing 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/UserMode8021X'
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.323 SC: <airportd[62494]> airportdProcessSystemConfigurationEvent: Processing 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/CachedScanRecord'
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.323 SC: <airportd[62494]> airportdProcessSystemConfigurationEvent: Processing 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/BluetoothAudioInUse'
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.323 SC: <airportd[62494]> airportdProcessSystemConfigurationEvent: Processing 'State:/Network/Interface/en0/AirPort/BusyUI'
Sun Jul 12 15:32:33.329 Info: <airportd[62494]> -[CWXPCInterfaceContext __setAWDLOperatingMode:interface:error:]: attempting to set AWDL mode to 2

Sun Jul 12 16:02:14.796 Info: <airportd[62494]> GET CURRENT TETHER DEVICE request received from pid 393 (SystemUIServer)
Sun Jul 12 16:02:31.995 Info: <WiFiAgent[370]> __WiFiCloudSyncEngineCopyLogStatementCallback_block_invoke: WIFICLOUDSYNC __WiFiCloudSyncEngineCheckWaitingForPasswordList: 68 networks waiting for password sync, currently at 15
Sun Jul 12 16:02:31.996 Info: <WiFiAgent[370]> __WiFiCloudSyncEngineCopyLogStatementCallback_block_invoke: WIFICLOUDSYNC __WiFiCloudSyncEngineCheckWaitingForPasswordList: Password is still not available for network at idx 15
Sun Jul 12 16:02:31.996 Info: <WiFiAgent[370]> __WiFiCloudSyncEngineCopyLogStatementCallback_block_invoke: WIFICLOUDSYNC __WiFiCloudSyncEngineCheckWaitingForPasswordList: 68 networks waiting for password sync, currently at 16
Sun Jul 12 16:02:31.996 Info: <WiFiAgent[370]> __WiFiCloudSyncEngineCopyLogStatementCallback_block_invoke: WIFICLOUDSYNC __WiFiCloudSyncEngineCheckWaitingForPasswordList: Password is still not available for network at idx 16
Sun Jul 12 16:02:31.996 Info: <WiFiAgent[370]> __WiFiCloudSyncEngineCopyLogStatementCallback_block_invoke: WIFICLOUDSYNC __WiFiCloudSyncEngineCheckWaitingForPasswordList: 68 networks waiting for password sync, currently at 17
Sun Jul 12 16:02:31.997 Info: <WiFiAgent[370]> __WiFiCloudSyncEngineCopyLogStatementCallback_block_invoke: WIFICLOUDSYNC __WiFiCloudSyncEngineCheckWaitingForPasswordList: Password is still not available for network at idx 17
Sun Jul 12 16:02:31.997 Info: <WiFiAgent[370]> __WiFiCloudSyncEngineCopyLogStatementCallback_block_invoke: WIFICLOUDSYNC __WiFiCloudSyncEngineCheckWaitingForPasswordList: 68 networks waiting for password sync, currently at 18
Sun Jul 12 16:02:31.997 Info: <WiFiAgent[370]> __WiFiCloudSyncEngineCopyLogStatementCallback_block_invoke: WIFICLOUDSYNC __WiFiCloudSyncEngineCheckWaitingForPasswordList: Password is still not available for network at idx 18
Sun Jul 12 16:02:31.997 Info: <WiFiAgent[370]> __WiFiCloudSyncEngineCopyLogStatementCallback_block_invoke: WIFICLOUDSYNC __WiFiCloudSyncEngineCheckWaitingForPasswordList: 68 networks waiting for password sync, currently at 19
Sun Jul 12 16:02:31.998 Info: <WiFiAgent[370]> __WiFiCloudSyncEngineCopyLogStatementCallback_block_invoke: WIFICLOUDSYNC __WiFiCloudSyncEngineCheckWaitingForPasswordList: Password is still not available for network at idx 19
Sun Jul 12 16:02:31.998 Info: <WiFiAgent[370]> __WiFiCloudSyncEngineCopyLogStatementCallback_block_invoke: WIFICLOUDSYNC __WiFiCloudSyncEngineCheckWaitingForPasswordList: max 'waiting for password' attempts reached (5 per 20.0s), next attempt scheduled for 22.0s from now
```

RN Diagnostics

```
# --- Diagnostics (RN)

————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
Timestamp    Name                          Duration    Result    Description                            
————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————————
Conflicting Wi-Fi CC                       0.002       Yes       16:02:31.970        Found conflicting country code(s) (ua)
                                                                                     'TP-LINK' — 10:fe:ed:fd:1d:68 (RU)
                                                                                     'RN' — 90:3a:72:3b:6f:d8 (US)
                                                                                     'RN' — 90:3a:72:3b:6f:dc (US)
HT40 2.4GHz Networks                       0.014       Yes       16:02:31.956        Found HT40 network(s) in 2.4GHz
                                                                                     'Strong jaguar' — 50:c7:bf:e5:d8:1c (ch 6)
                                                                                     'Home WIFI' — 28:3b:82:31:16:0a (ch 9)
Large PNL                                  0.019       Yes       16:02:31.913        Wi-Fi PNL count (270)
AirPort Base Station                       0.001       No        16:02:31.896        Current network is not an AirPort Base Station
Uncommon DTIM Interval                     0.001       Yes       16:02:31.886        DTIM interval is 0ms
BT Paired Count                            0.050       Yes       16:02:31.831        Paired Bluetooth device count (6)
Primary IPv6 is Wi-Fi                      0.000       No        16:02:31.829        None
IPv6 Assigned                              0.000       No        16:02:31.827        Wi-Fi does not have IPv6 assigned
Wi-Fi Link                                 0.000       No        15:32:30.854        Wi-Fi is not associated
```

Comment: I'm getting disconnected multiple times a day on a brand new MacBook Pro (16-inch, 2019). My previous MacBook Air does not have this problem. There's a [related Apple Community thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251223376?page=1). Lots of hacks to try in that thread, but no definitive fix.

Comment: Did you get a correct analysis and a fix to this WI-Fi connection drops?

Answer (score 1):

Note that RN Diagnostics indicates you have conflicting country codes: some are US, some are RU (Russia). If your router transmits a different country code than what your macbook thinks it should be, then this can apparently cause problems with re-connecting. Check your router setup to see if the country code (or region) can be changed. Hopefully you have control over the affected routers to make this change.